# How to convert this second conditional sentence into third one (conventional definitions)?

Tags: conditional-constructions, clauses

expression about unreal situation without any time marker (second conditional)

1) if you could see him would you say him?

---

Question:

- How to convert foregoing second conditional sentence into third one?

if you **had** could see him **yesterday**, would have you said him?

OR

If you could have seen him yesterday, would have you said him?

Answer (score 2):

Your starting sentence is incorrect.  I'm going to assume you mean:

> If you could see him **what** would you say **to** him?

To shift:

> If you **could have seen** him (yesterday), what would you **have said** to him?

Only the verbs change.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean 'tomorrow', supposedly had written by mistake and deleted it already. Thank you for your concern

Comment: @Max Ok, edited.  It really doesn't make much difference.